# osmium export returrns "too many positional options have been specified on the command line"

Tags: export, osmium

I'm using the following line to export roads from an OSM file:

`osmium export tags-filter nw/highway -o roads.geojson africa-latest.osm`

I keep getting "Error parsing command line: too many positional options have been specified on the command line"

I've tried all sorts of variations on this and checked up the help commands. I can't see how I can drop any of the options